# check if div has child multiple clickling button

Tags: jquery

I tried a lot of if conditions but it still making the same thing: i have grid and list view buttons for product cards. I need to when i click list view button some elements from from grid view to change their positions. In this example its category-tag.
so i have

```
$('.filter__layout-button--list').on('click', function () {
    $('.category-page__products').addClass('list'),
     $('.product-card').addClass('list'),
     $('.product-card__review-category').children().addClass('list'),
     $('.category-tag.list').insertAfter($('.product-card__top-description'))
  })


$('.filter__layout-button--grid').on('click', function () {
    $('.category-page__products').removeClass('list'),
    $('.product-card__review-category').children().removeClass('list'),
    if ($('.product-card__info-bottom--categorypage').children('.category-tag--categorypage').length === 0) {
      $('.category-tag--categorypage').insertAfter($('.product-card__bottom-price'))
    }
  })
```

the problem is, that is works fine until i change my view points 3 times. After thhree times, my category-tag elements multiply by three every time i click back and forth...i dont understand why it's happening when i have if condition...please help!

Comment: Adding demo code with html might help to understand where problem exist .

Comment: and add css in addition

Comment: @Swati FYI you can add `[mcve]` in your comment to auto-link to the [mcve] help.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you . Between where are these shortcut found ?